# VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount returns 0 when run from MainPage_Loaded

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

In my WP7 app, I'm using this guys method to find a `TextBlock` within a `ToggleButton`.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1759923/1339857

When I make the call while the app is running it works fine.
If I try and make the exact same call from `MainPage_Loaded`, `FindChild` returns `null`.

Here's the simple call

```
TextBlock myText = FindChild<TextBlock>(myToggle, "toggleTitle");  
myText.Text = "Some text";
```

It looks like it's because `VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount` is returning 0.

Why would it have a value when the app is running but not from `MainPage_Loaded`? Is'nt the purpose of `MainPage_Loaded` to wait until the app is loaded before firing off events?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One trick you can use to deal with this is to queue up your call on the Loaded event. So in the MainPage_Loaded handler wrap your call in a [Dispatcher.BeginInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190259%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => {
  TextBlock myText = FindChild<TextBlock>(myToggle, "toggleTitle");  
  myText.Text = "Some text";
}
```

This will add your call to the queue and it will get called after the current event cycle has completed (which should be when all the child items have been loaded).